# Quartz scheduler: Register multiiple jobs under same trigger

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I'm new to the Quartz scheduler. I had few queries and hope someone give a hand here. Thanks a lot!

First of all, let me share with you on my way to organize the jobs and triggers in single Scheduler:

1. One trigger group, many triggers with unique name
2. Many job groups, many jobs with unique name inside one group
3. One job group may associate with one trigger so that all jobs under this group will be fired at the same time

I think this organization is quite normal in scheduler software. However, I only found references to register same job with multiple triggers. Even though, I still thought to register many jobs with the same trigger is achievable logically.

Following is my own logic to achieve the goal:

1. Job A be created, Trigger A be created, call function scheduleJob(JobA, TriggerA) to register Job A with Scheduler firstly
2. Job B be created, get Trigger A from Scheduler based on its unique name, call function scheduleJob(JobB, TriggerA) to register Job B with Scheduler later

Therefore, refer to my own logic, I had two queries:

1. Is it possible to implement getting Trigger A from Scheduler based on its name ?
2. Is it a correct way to register multiple jobs with same trigger by using scheduleJob() function again and again ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, a job can have many triggers relating to it, but a trigger can only relate to one job. Though you can get something of the effect you're after if you use a job/trigger listener and schedule triggers to fire other jobs immediately when the one trigger fires.

You can set up multiple identical triggers, one for each job.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jeevan. I have checked the Trigger Interface API, you are right about it.

Comment: @ShadowScorpion please can you provide code script about your solution?

Comment: @Jeevan Patil Can we schedule multiple jobs with multiple tiggers for each with a single scheduler instance?